# Errors: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'

Tags: sql

I am trying to pull a query of everyone who opened an email, where the emailname contains the word 'offer'. However,I am getting the error:

> Errors: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where
>   a condition is expected, near ')'.

```
SELECT j.Emailname, j.JobID
FROM   _Job j
WHERE  j.Emailname LIKE 'offer%'
AND (
    SELECT o.SubscriberKey, o.JobID
    FROM   _Open o
    WHERE  o.JobID = j.JobID
)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You don't compare the sub-query result to anything.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Comment: Please specify database you're using in tags

Comment: An "open" table seems a bit odd... I'd take another look at the db design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `AND` expects a `Boolean` but you give it a sub-query that returns records.

Maybe you want to use `EXISTS` (selecting `1` because columns don't matter in `EXISTS`/`NOT EXISTS`):

```
SELECT j.Emailname, j.JobID
FROM   _Job j
WHERE  j.Emailname LIKE 'offer%'
AND EXIST(
    SELECT 1
    FROM   _Open o
    WHERE  o.JobID = j.JobID
)
```

Comment: @JaylovesSQL, if you're accepting the answer, please click on the grey check mark to the left. That marks the question as answered, and gives the appropriate points to the person who provided the help.